# BS4 - "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am unable to extract the data from this webpage using bs4 by getting the following error

```
"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'"
```

can someone revise my code?

here is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://e-masjid.jais.gov.my/index.php/profail?page=1'

html_content = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'lxml')

masjid_table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "Masjid"})
masjid_table_data = masjid_table.tbody.find_all("tr")

headings = []
for td in masjid_table_data[0].find_all("td"):
    headings.append(td.b.text.replace('\n', ' ').strip())

print(headings)masjid_table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "Masjid"})

masjid_table_data = masjid_table.tbody.find_all("tr")

headings = []
for td in masjid_table_data[0].find_all("td"):
    headings.append(td.b.text.replace('\n', ' ').strip())

print(headings)
```

Comment: What's it your are trying to extract, can you add some sample output ?

Comment: try print(soup), whats the output.

Comment: you can check output here

https://pastebin.com/nrhL7RPB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I don't know what your desired output is.. This will get you all the masjid names..

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content.text, 'lxml')

masjid_table = soup.find("table", attrs={"id": "pemohon"})
masjid_table_data = masjid_table.tbody.find_all("tr")

headings = []
for row in masjid_table_data:
    headings.append(row.find_all('td')[1].text.replace('\nMASJID', ' ').strip())
```

You can try changing the index here `row.find_all('td')[1]` to get respective columns.

Answer (score 0):

An attribute error means that you are calling an attribute that doesn't exist for a given object. 
In your case, `requests.get(url)` is returning None, so `requests.get(url).text` is the same as `None.text`, which is invalid.
If that is expected, check if the request returns something:

```
result = requests.get(url)
if result:
    string = requests.get(url).text
```